# Infinite Scroll: no counter reset

Tags: php, wordpress, post, counter, infinite-scroll

I'm using Infinite Scroll for my WordPress site on the category page and it works like charm. On the category page I added a counter in php. And if the counter % 4 == 0 a specific class will be added to the postclass.

But if I scroll down the category page and the infinite scroll loads new posts, the counter will be reseted (=0).

How can I contiune the counter while loading new posts? 
I already tried with a  global variable, but that didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I noticed that infinite scroll does add a page number to each block that it loads. So I peeked at infinite.php to see how it's done. Basically it looks at the query to see which page/block we're on.

Then you can set the counter properly, like so:

```
$counter = $wp_query->current_post;
$page = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
$counter = $page*7+$counter;
```

Or if you want to start with 0 on the extra loaded pages, because you already counted the first 7: (It's 7 because that's what the WordPress infinite scroll uses.)

```
$counter = $wp_query->current_post;
$page = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
$counter = ($page - 1)*7+$counter;
```

You can probably think of an even nicer way of doing this...